# Is Using REST for authentication a good practice?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

As I understand, when using REST services we count on the URI to request data and so in an authentication service, we would need to send the username & password through the URL, which is bad, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your authentication service should be a POST, which will keep the credentials out of the URL. As long as the service runs over HTTPS (it does, right?), then you're safe from prying eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add data to the URL, you can also Post to a REST service.